# How to clear HTML5 application cache of UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, browser-cache

I've faced with an issue recently that HTML5 application cache stopped work in native container which uses UIWebView to render html content. cache.manifest file was changed, UIWebView started downloading process but failed at some file. In iPad's Safari everything worked fine. As you know there is no way to get known about app cache errors from JavaScript. So I wanted to clear cache completely and start from scratch. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling of native app doesn't help. The only way to clean up HTML5 application cache is to use following steps:

1. Download iFunBox http://www.i-funbox.com/
2. Connect device and run iFunBox
3. Open following path Connected Devices=>Your Device Name=>User Applications=>Your native container app name=>Library=>Caches=>com.apple.WebAppCache
4. Remove ApplicationCache.db and com.apple.WebAppCache folder itself
5. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

From your native container you can clear the sqlite database the UIWebview uses to implement the HTML5 application cache.

I wrote an article about it with some sample code included: [Clear the HTML5 Application Cache of an UIWebView](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/clear-the-html5-application-cache-of-an-uiwebview)